# HTML5 ellipses render incorrectly with really large stroke width

Tags: javascript, html, svg

My situation is pretty simple. If you draw a small ellipse, with a really large stroke width then the browser renders the ellipse with a weird 'cat eye' effect.

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MyBsC/4/

```
<svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <ellipse cx="80" cy="80" rx="8" ry="10" style="fill:yellow;stroke:purple;stroke-width:50"/>
</svg>
```

If you play around with the fiddle and make the ellipse larger, the effect goes away. It happens both with SVG ellipses and with ellipses drawn inside a canvas.

I have observed this behaviour on Firefox 21.0, Chrome 26, and Safari 5.1.7 on Mac OSX Lion

Does anyone know why this happens? Is this a bug with the browsers? Or is there a CSS property I am missing?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you see? I don't see a "cat eye" effect.

Comment: Image here: http://postimg.org/image/q1ld0ef65/